# Using Database Views with Rails and Postgres to calculate moving average

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table called `Races` with associated `Laps` where I store lap-level data from races. The lap data looks like this:

```
id        racer_id    lap_time  lap_speed   laps_completed  race_id
1         1234           33.5     160              1           1
2         1234           33.5     160              2           1
3         1234           31.25    162              3           1
4         1234           31.25    162              4           1
5         1234           29.5     165              5           1
6         1234           32       161              6           1
7         5678           35       153              1           1
8         5678           35       155              2           1
9         5678           32       158              3           1
10        5678           33.5     160              4           1
11        5678           33       159              5           1
12        5678           32       158              6           1
```

What I am trying to do is calculate which racer's from each race have the highest and lowest rolling lap average speeds (Based on a 2-lap average).

What I have right now is a database view that I have added to my migrations:

```
class CreateLapAverageView < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE VIEW rolling_lap_averages AS
        SELECT id,
               racer_id,
               race_id,
               laps_completed,
               AVG(lap_speed)
               OVER(ORDER BY laps_completed ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS lap_average_2
        FROM laps
      SQL
  end

  def down
    execute("DROP VIEW rolling_lap_averages")
  end
end
```

From running the raw SQL query, this is what I want, but now I am now entirely sure how to use this within my Rails app. Secondarily, is it possible to pass parameters to database views in Rails? For example, instead of `OVER(ORDER BY laps_completed ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` I would like to do something like `OVER(ORDER BY laps_completed ROWS BETWEEN $1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)` to change the window size?

Comment: Not sure about your underlying RDS, but take a look at windowing functions -- likely an easier path than trying to do this in Rails.

Comment: Using Postgres. I'll take a look at it!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is quite broad currently. We have no idea your level of expertise, what you've written to this point, which, to cover an answer in detail would result in writing a tutorial. Instead, see "[ask]" and the linked pages and ask about a specific problem.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks for the feedback! Updated with additional info

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model that will access data from your `rolling_lap_averages` table just like any other model:

```rb
class RollingLapAverage < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = :id

  belongs_to :race
  belongs_to :racer

  def readonly?
    true
  end
end

avg = RollingLapAverage.find(6)
avg.lap_speed # => 162.666666667
```